# Add a user clickable check box in SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, bids

I am creating a report that for the most part is populated automatically by using variables, parameters with my datasource and dataset. I am trying to add in another column that will have a checkbox, where when the user pulls a report he or she can manually go in and click a check box for various rows. The clicked check box is done by the user and there is no need to send or retrieve data with this check box. Is there a simple solution to where I can add a checkbox for the user to check (and uncheck) various boxes?

Answer (score 0):

SSRS does not deliver this kind of functionality. You would need to have a flag for every displayed row somewhere in your database and add two images to your report, a checked and one unchecked "checkbox" image, show those images on each row (source over expression) based on the flag of the row. Add an action to the image, that executes a storedProc and flags or unflags the row (pass an unambiguous id as parameter).
This is rather dirty, but would work.